# Is 1.5 hour layover at Frankfurt enough to connect to Munich?

Tags: germany, layovers, munich, lufthansa, frankfurt

My flight goes BOS - FRA - MUC - BOM
I have a 1.5 hour layover at Frankfurt to get through border control to Lufthansa's terminal to take my flight to Munich.

Is that sufficient ? I've only found similar questions but nothing about two layovers in Germany. Hence the question.

Comment: Single ticket or multiple tickets ?

Comment: @Hilmar Single ticket

Comment: Then you are fine. No need for dealing with bags and another check in. 1.5 hours is plenty of time. Even if there is an issue the airline will take care of you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a SFO -> FRA -> LIN with 1 hour layover. Milan (LIN) it's inside the EU like Munich, so the timings are roughly the same.

I did it comfortably.

Comment: Right. But they're in two different schengen states, so you would not have had to cross the border control. Or, did you ?
If you did, did you have have to take your bags and check them in again on your connecting flight ?

Comment: When it comes to border controls, there is only Schengen, not Schengen states. So it doesn't matter if you're connecting to Italy, Germany or Austria, you will always go through border control on the first airport where you enter Schengen. In your case as well as Napolux case, that is FRA.

Comment: Regarding bags, as long as they are checked through by the airline, you don't pick them up. If your flights are on one ticket, the bags should be checked completely through.

Comment: @dunni When talking about 'border controls' in this case, you have to distinguish between immigration control and customs control. You will go through immigration in the first Schengen country you are transiting in, but not go through customs until you are at your final destination.

Comment: Right, my statements are only correct for immigration controls.